# Deploy WebJobs with Web App using Web Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm migrating a Web App project to a new Azure account. Everything works fine but the Web Jobs are not included when publishing.

`webjobs-list.json` is identical, the publishing profiles are identical etc., just the Web Jobs are missing.

I can deploy them individually, though.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you need to check.

NO 1. The file path in webjobs-list.json is right. You could find the WebJob project file according this file.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
  "WebJobs": [
    {
      "filePath": "../WebJob1/WebJob1.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

NO 2. Open the project file of your web application(ex. myapp.csproj). Please check whether it has been modified and lost following Import configuration section.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```

Comment: Thanks, both exist and are fine. Is there a potential conflict/bug between 1.0.12 and 1.0.13 ? When I click on the Web App (right click) and add one of the WebJobs, a reference to 1.0.12 is added.

Comment: I'm currently successfully deploying all Web Jobs in one go with a reference to 1.0.13 - just to another Azure account. I'm suspecting there's a bug because it might be a rare and not well tested case to deploy the same project to multiple Azure accounts.

Comment: I tested 1.0.12 and 1.0.13, both worked fine on my side. The issue maybe accidentally and can not be reproduced.

Comment: Seems like it, maybe a VS issue. Will amend should I find a fix

Comment: The Microsoft documentation says you need to have Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish added to the web job project, but it doesn't mention that you need to have it added to the web app project as well. Things started working properly for me after adding it to the web app project.

Comment: This stuff is buggy. I am running into numerous problems with vs 2019 and web job deployment.

Comment: On VS2019 the NO2 code doesn't get added to my webapp.csproj file